# Chaining/Combining query strings in .htaccess. Is this possible?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to chain or combine query strings when writing RewriteCond or RewriteRules?

At the moment I have this in my .htaccess file…

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tiger [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} tiger
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/news/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lion [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} lion
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/news/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} cheetah [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} cheetah
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/news/? [L,R=301]
```

All three matches are going to the same destination. Is it possible to do something like this or do I need to keep them all as separate lines?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (tiger, lion, cheetah) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (tiger, lion, cheetah)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/news/? [L,R=301]
```

Here is my htaccess file as is…

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex alternation:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (tiger|lion|cheetah) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (tiger|lion|cheetah) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/news/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava - Unfortunately I've tried your second code in place of the code I already have and it's not working :-( Does it matter where it's placed within the .htaccess file?

Comment: Yes it does matter. This rule should be right below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Hmmm strange. I've tried that but the second option isn't working. Your first bit of code works fine however. Would it help if I pasted the content of my .htaccess file?

Comment: Sorry - I have no idea how to add formatting to comment code

Comment: oh not in comments, add this htaccess by editing your question

Comment: Actually I realized that 2nd version is anding conditions together instead of ORing. So yes only the shown rule in updated answer will work.